# Creating ISO images from already installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 & 14.04 on commandline

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, 14.10, 16.10

I am using Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS. I need to make an .ISO image from it. The trouble is that all tools i have come across use GUI. Ubuntu Server on the other hand does not come with GUI.

Are there ways of creating an ISO image from an already installed Ubuntu OS on command line?

Answer (score 0):

It should be super easy using dd...

```
sudo dd if=/dev/mydrive of=image.iso
```

You could also clone one drive to another like this:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/mydrive of=/dev/myothersd
```

Just be careful. "if" is the input file and "of" the output file. Messing up these values could nuke your system. Make sure you know what drive is what using:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

when you figure out what drive you want to use your command will look something like this (to clone the entire drive):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=mydrive.iso
```

***DO NOT just copy and paste the above command or any dd command. When using dd ALWAYS confirm correct drive paths!***

An example of cloning a partition, looks like this:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=mydrive.iso
```

For more information, check out the manpage

```
man dd
```

Note: When using dd, it gives you no progress or output while it's doing its thang. It will take a while and show no progress, don't worry, just wait.

Comment: Thank you   It did not work I was able to work image iso But did not work at installation

Comment: It creates files on the USB disk, but when I try to boot the USB disk it shows an Operating System Not Found error.

Comment: USB drives are set up differently and have a different boot sector, so you can't just clone your drive to a usb drive and expect it to work. USB drives need to be created specially in order to boot\

Comment: all you asked in your question was how to make an ISO of your drive

Comment: I'm extracting iso to /home Then after I install ubuntu-desktop To get to iso Am I wrong about that?

Comment: im not sure I understand... are you just wanting to clone your home folder?

Comment: I do not want to copy the entire system to give to a friend

Comment: Extract them to the home file  :  sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=~/ubuntu-image.iso

Comment: I am so sorry, but I am super confused now :( Do you just want to clone your home folder or are you trying to clone your system between two machines? Unfortunately you can't just clone an internal drive to an external drive and boot off of that.... what are you trying? just to backup your system? if so, cloning to an ISO then cloning that to an internal drive and installing that to another computer will work... cloning to a usb drive will not boot... :(

Comment: I am  are you trying to clone you system between two machines?